# How to write a single hex value to file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, hex

I'm trying to write a single-hex value, say 'F' to a file:

```
a = int('F', 16)
f.write(chr(a))
```

However, this code segment gives me the file with `0F`. I just want the single hex `F` in my file. I know this is because a char is represented by a byte, is there a way to directly write the hex value without the pad?

Comment: Are you looking for a ASCII Hex value in your file (0x70), or the binary value of 0xF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible on most modern operating systems.  The smallest data unit that a general purpose computing platform can handle is is one byte.

Check this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) for additional details where in it it states:
"Historically, the byte was the number of bits used to encode a single character of text in a computer and for this reason it is the smallest addressable unit of memory in many computer architectures. "

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
 f.write("{:X}".format(a))
```

It will write it as `F`:

```
 >>> "{:X}".format(a)
 'F'
```

Comment: actually, this just gives the string 'F', what I want is the value 0xF in my raw file.

Comment: but in your question "I just want the single hex F in my file. ", no?

Comment: This is the same as `f.write('F') and writes the hex value `0x46`.

Comment: I don't want hex value `0x46` or `0x0F` but rather just `0xF` written into my file.

Comment: I dont understand, if you checking for hex value, so 0x0F and 0xF are same value?

Comment: @Abundance I'm still puzzled... do you want 3 characters "0xF" or a single binary byte? Since a byte is 8 bits and a hex F is only 4 bits, `0xF` and `0x0F` are the same thing.

Comment: Do files have to be written in multiple of bytes? I can't write just `0xF` to a file? Because if I write that same char twice I get `0x0F0F` where I want `0xFF`

Comment: @Abundance you are unclear here,  left zeroes are insignificant so 0x0F ==  0xF, not the same case with 0x0F0F and 0xFF

Comment: What is unclear? The left zero will still remain in the file, so whenever I write something else, it will be significant. I want to be writing exactly 4 bits instead of a byte.

Comment: @Abundance - A byte is the smallest addressable or writable entity on PCs and most standard hardware. `0xF` is a 4 bit nibble but you always have to deal in 8 bit bytes.

Comment: Okay, I see. So it's not really possible

Comment: You can do it if you write your own accessors. For instance, if counting by nibbles, odd number nibbles (the 2nd nibble) in a byte could be set by reading the byte, updating the upper 4 bits and then writing the byte again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `struct` module to write raw data to a file. This will write a single byte to the file

```
open('file','wb').write(struct.pack('b', 0xf))
```

Comment: the answer writes `0x0f` to the file

Comment: Yes, so the question remains, What Do You Want Written??

Comment: `0x0f` and `0xf` are both `00001111` as a binary byte. `0x0f` is just a human readable form of the byte... of course `00001111` is too...